# Protractor: Page Object returns "promise" instead of Text

Tags: protractor

I have this page object method :

```
this.userName = async function(){
    if(environment === 'AWS'){
        return 'user1'
    }else{
        return'user2'
    }
};
```

When the script is run, it returns the following:

```
Promise { 'user1' }
```

Is there a way to return only the text "user1", not as a promise?

Comment: It's an `async` function, that's what it's supposed to return.

Comment: By declaring your function `async` you are declaring that it will return a promise, regardless of whether or not you explicitly use the promise syntax. If you do not have async actions then there is no need to declare your function as async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite it to:

```
// option 1
this.userName = await async function(){

// option 2
this.userName = function(){

// and rest of the code
    if(environment === 'AWS'){
        return 'user1'
    }else{
        return'user2'
    }
};
```